# How to find how much dashes in given paragraph using PHP?

Tags: php

I have Below Paragraph. I want to Find Number of Dashes araises in given paragraph??

```
1.I opened ______ door and found ______ old man wearing ______ hat standing on _____ doorstep.
```

Is Possible??

Comment: What actually you want?? you want to remove or replaced with something else?

Comment: ______ is count to be a single dash or you have to count it like separate underscores??

Comment: echo substr_count($text, '_');

Comment: i need to find how much dashes in given paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Just declare your text in a variable and count it

```
<?php
$text = "1.I opened ______ door and found ______ old man wearing ______ hat standing on _____ doorstep.";
echo substr_count($text,"_______");
?>
```

Note : It will count the number of `_____` . [Dashes `_____` is `5`in count]

Here is the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4421d2fc07285617928263a9372c519efc215a10)

Comment: But $text = "1.I opened ____(5 dashes) old man wearing ______ (8 dashes)that standing on. then how i calculate??

Comment: It was totally `23`  for the entire text . You can see the demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81021b99efa2e42d9894ba2a3628f525b42f6672)

Comment: Its Rignt. But I Want                                                                                             $text = "1.I opened ___the___ door and found ______ old man wearing ______ hat standing on _____ doorstep."; calculate dashes and fill that how many right answer.

Comment: It will count the number or `_` occurrence. You want to show the output as `4` as only 4 long dashes are there ?

Comment: Ok, Here is the updated code that matches your requirement in the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4421d2fc07285617928263a9372c519efc215a10) and i have updated it in my question too

Comment: But I client add a text like ( I opened ______(5 dashes) door and found ______(7 dashes)  old man wearing ________(10 dashes)  hat standing on _____ doorstep."; the HOw i calculate here 4 dashe??

Comment: then you should add the `$first =  substr_count($text,"_____");` (5 dashes) `$second =  substr_count($text,"_______");` (7 dashes) `$third =  substr_count($text,"__________");` (10 dashes) and then add the `$first` ,`$second`, `$third`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the OP wants to count the number of words to be filled in represented by a series of underscores.

The number of underscores can also vary, I'm guessing to represent the length of the word.

So a more generic solution would be...
Set the regex for the desired pattern

```
$search_string = '/[^_]?[_]+[^_]?/'; // Looking for one or more '_' sequences
```

A simpler version would be

```
$search_string = '/[_]{2,}/'; // Looking for at least 2 '_' sequences
```

Perform the blank word count where needed.

```
$word_count = preg_match_all($search_string,$text);
echo $word_count; // Just show the count for testing
```

The regex is pretty generic but should work for the above cases.

Additional: You are much better off creating a function to implement this.

```
function count_blank_words($text){
    $search_string = '/[_]{2,}/'; // Looking for at least 2 '_' sequences
    return preg_match_all($search_string,$text);
}
```

and call it using

```
echo count_blank_words($text);
```